# Fail to call last if condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Currently I'm working with jQuery. My question is, why when I filled all the text box and click submit button, why is it not going to `'/timesheets_app/index.php/searchall'`? Here is my snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search-form").submit(function() {
        if ($("#fieldDari").val() == '' && $("#fieldKe").val() == '' && $("#fieldNama").val() == '')
        {
            $("#search-form").attr("action", "/timesheets_app/index.php/karyawan2");
        } else if ($("#fieldDari").val() == '' && $("#fieldKe").val() == '')
        {
            $("#search-form").attr("action", "/timesheets_app/index.php/searchname");
        } else if ($("#fieldNama").val() == '')
        {
            $("#search-form").attr("action", "/timesheets_app/index.php/searchdate");
        } else if ($("#fieldNama").val() != '' && $("#fieldDari").val() != '' && $("#fieldKe").val() != ''){
            $("#search-from").attr("action", "/timesheets_app/index.php/searchall");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you find out which `if-part` is working?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the debugger? Are these all `input` fields?

Comment: How do you know .val() isn't working? It's more likely that your if conditional simply isn't logically correct.

Comment: @KevinB hummmm, so, how to reach last else if? Here is the condition: I filled all the textbox, so I can meet the condition in last else if?

Comment: debug it. What is the value of each of the textboxes according to .val in that case?

Comment: I updated my answer to include the second typo in that last if-statement.  Let me know if there are still issues.

Comment: @KevinB is right. You're lacking the most basic debugging efforts. Also, if you'd use variables to avoid all that repeated typing, you'd avoid errors.

Comment: @KevinB +1 suggestion for debugging, thank's to all suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a .val() on the last one.

```
$("#fieldKe").val() != ''
```

You also have a typo on the$("#search-form").attr(...)

Comment: There's another typo inside the last if-statement.  You have $("#search-from")...

Comment: Yes, I'm missing "#search-from", thank you very much

Comment: No problem, any time!

Answer (score 1):

In

`else if ($("#fieldNama").val() != '' && $("#fieldDari").val() != '' && $("#fieldKe") != '')`

`$("#fieldKe") != ''`

should be changed to

`$("#fieldKe").val() != ''`